# c# filter list of objects at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects that I want to filter based on some information. For example list of fruits that may have different fruits. from this list of fruits I want to get a new list of only fruits that match a certain criteria.

I have:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruitList(List<Fruit> allFruits, string fruitType, string fruitColor) {

 List<Fruit> newFruits = allFruits.Where(f => f.typeOfFruit == fruitType)
                               .Where(f => f.fruitColor == fruitColor).ToList();
 return newFruits;
}
```

but what happens if someone wants all fruit types, but wants to specify only on color (red, meaning red apples and strawberries should appear in the new list)? this means that the fruitType parameter can come as "All", which would not filter out any fruit based on that criteria.

the fruits in the list though, don't have a typeOfFruit value of "All" so the filter will return no results because no fruit had that value "All"

I saw something like this:

```
query = fruitColor == "All" ? query : query.Where(x => x.fruitColor == fruitColor);
query = fruitType == "All" ? query : query.Where(x => x.typeOfFruit == fruitType);
```

and build a query this way, however I don't know what kind of object this "query" is. Is it a string? or is there some sort of "Query" class that I can use to build a query expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple modification to take care of **ALL** the fruit types would be..

```
List<Fruit> newFruits = allFruits.Where(f => f.typeOfFruit == fruitType || fruitType == "All")
                               .Where(f => f.fruitColor == fruitColor).ToList();
```

The `f.typeOfFruit == fruitType || fruitType == "All"` part would take care of a particular criteria of the fruit `OR` **All** types of fruits, respectively

Your LINQ can further be simplified to

```
List<Fruit> newFruits = allFruits
                        .Where(f => (f.typeOfFruit == fruitType || fruitType == "All") 
                                 && f.fruitColor == fruitColor).ToList();
```

Comment: can you explain what that top line is doing with the or '||'

Comment: I think! It should not be `f.typeOfFruit`...!

Comment: Instead of f.typeOfFruit it should be fruitType like this `f => (f.typeOfFruit == fruitType || fruitType == "All")`

Comment: There isn't a fruit of type "All". The "All" is possible parameter in the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `System.Linq` then it should be `IQueryable`.  You can see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Edit:  Adding `Enumerable.Where` documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how you can dynamically build linq queries:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruitList(List<Fruit> allFruits, string fruitType, string fruitColor) 
{

    IEnumerable<Fruit> newFruits = allFruits;

    if(fruitType != "All")
    {
        newFruites = newFruits.Where(f => f.typeOfFruit == fruitType);
    }
    if(fruitColor != "All")
    {
        newFruits = newFruits.Where(f => f.fruitColor == fruitColor);
    }
    return newFruits.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I see, but I'm trying to avoid multi if/else blocks, I should've clarified in the question, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just pass a null or empty string for the parameter you do not want to filter by

```js
public List<Fruit> getFruitList(List<Fruit> allFruits, string fruitType, string fruitColor) {

 bool filterByFruitType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fruitType);
 bool filterByFruitColor = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fruitColor);
 
 // both type and color
 if (filterByFruitType && filterByFruitColor) {
  return allFruits.Where(f => f.typeOfFruit == fruitType)
                               .Where(f => f.fruitColor == fruitColor).ToList();
 }
 // color only
 else if (!filterByFruitType && filterByFruitColor) {
  return allFruits.Where(f => f.fruitColor == fruitColor).ToList();
 }
 // type only
 else if (filterByFruitType && !filterByFruitColor) {
  return allFruits.Where(f => f.typeOfFruit == fruitType).ToList();
 }
 // no filter
 else {
  return allFruits;
 }
}
```